# Where the term "tarball" comes from?

Tags: tar

I use unix distros every day and I started using them a long time ago but I never thought about the provenience of the word "tarball". I tried to search it on the dictionary but I didn't find anything.
At this point it could also be a completely invented term but I thought "better to ask".

Comment: *tarball` comes from the `tar` (tape-archive) software. It refers to the file archives that include several files. If you use zip files, tarballs are something similar.

Comment: It rolls easier off the tongue than "tar archive" -- and unix geeks would detest the latter on general principle for being redundant as `tar` stands for **T**ape **AR**chive...

Comment: @perror thanks for the answer but maybe you missed "I use unix distros every day and I started using them a long time ago". I know what they are, i was just trying to figure out where the Tarball term comes from.

Comment: @shadur yes I know that tar stands for Tape Archive, but what tarball stands for? why that "ball"

Comment: I think that simply comes from the actual word tar - and tarball being a piece of tar.

Comment: Ir's a bit like a "furball" with cats, it's a pack of things glued together by cat's fur. So, here, it's a pack of files glued together by `tar`... I guess... But, there is probably no deep meaning behind the scene, just a small joke made by computer scientist (at this time they were really funny, not as "corporate" as today! :-)).

Comment: @perror Thank you very much perror :D I love cats and as I explained in the other comments I want to take your answer as "the true answer", I like to image this files glued like furball hahahah

Comment: @perror : Hey, if you're still around.  It looks to me like you'd have an opportunity to get some reputation if you'd just copy your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's a joke.

`tar` (Tape ARchive) is the name of the program used to create an archive that contains several files, all glued together.

*Tar* is also a black and sticky substance obtained from hydrocarbons. It translates to *catrame* in Italian (from your name, I suppose you're Italian).

Therefore, if you take a bunch of files and stick and roll all of them together via the `tar` program, you obtain a *tar ball* or *tarball*.

Comment: oh yes I'm italian and thank you for your explanation! Since there is no official meaning for the word "tarball" I'd prefer to take as "true" the answer of perror about cats :DDDD

Comment: Also, in real life a tar ball is a lump of solidified crude oil found in or on the sea, or washed up on shore.

Comment: i thought it was a more dirty joke that linus torvalds made XD